# TypeScript Generic - Same keys as another object, but all types as 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

Given a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
   foo: string;
   bar: number;
   baz: Date;
}
```

I want to create a generic type called `Transmuted<T>` that would return this interface:

```
interface TransmutedFoo {
   foo: any
   bar: any
   baz: any
}
```

How can I create this generic?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8O6N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? Note: it won't work for private fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `class Foo {/*...*/}`, TypeScript creates a type called `Foo` to represent instances of the class. So fundamentally, your question comes down to: How do I convert one object type to another type with the same keys?

The answer is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content):

```typescript
type Transmuted<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: any;
};
```

`[Key in keyof T]` lists the property keys of `T`, and what appears after the `:` is the type for those properties. In this case, it's a very simple mapped type since it maps everything to `any`.

Applying that to `Foo` gives us:

```
class Foo {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    baz: Date;

    constructor() {
        this.foo = "";
        this.bar = 0;
        this.baz = new Date();
    }
}

type Transmuted<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: any;
};

type TransmutedFoo = Transmuted<Foo>;
//   ^? type TransmutedFoo = { foo: any; bar: any; baz: any };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQGaIFzQgBcAnASwDsBzAbnUwCMxj9yBXAW3oFNjbNpGAL3wARMIS606GYPHJFirYIXjEAFAEoU0-tEIALUhAB0OJAF5oAIit9dGA0eONi0SwAY79xyaFvo5FwA7tBiEppe0AC+qDGohACeAA5c0AAqxGDy7KwSACYAPGkAfP5o-ADaANJcCdAU0ADWtfBY6QC6+FkJtFFSiSnpmdm5XHkIFkNZEDn5BRPFtAD0S5gAegD8QA)

In this specific case, since you want all of the properties to have the same type, you could use the built-in generic type [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) as [Aluan Haddad points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299743/typescript-generic-same-keys-as-another-object-but-all-types-as-any/76299827?noredirect=1#comment134553104_76299827) rather than writing it explicitly as above. `Record` *"Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type."* (And it's implemented by doing exactly what we do above: `{ [P in Keys]: Type; }`.) So you could do:

```typescript
type Transmuted<T> = Record<keyof T, any>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQGaIFzQgBcAnASwDsBzAbnUwCMxj9yBXAW3oFNjbNpGAL3wARMIS606GYPHJFirYIXjEAFAEoU0-tEIALUhAB0OJAF5oAIit9dGA0eONi0SwAY79xyaFvo5FwA7tBiEppe0AC+qDGohACeAA5c0AAqxGDy7KwSACYAPGkAfP4ASlyyxIUA1lwJ8FjpADTQWQnFUokp6ZnZuVx5CBa9WRA5+QXDnagA9LOYAHoA-EA)

Comment: The `Record` utility type provided by the language has the desired semantics (`type Transmuted<T> = Record<keyof T, any>;`) but I think it's good that you illustrate how one can define it on their own.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - OMG, how did I overlook that? :-) Thanks!

Comment: `Record<keyof T, any>` doesn't work for my case, it doesn't handle optional fields. Get a type error similar to:`'id' is required in Transmated<T> but optional in T`

Comment: @MaverikMinett - Well, there were no optional fields in your question. If you have something other than what you've shown, show it and we can try to help you with it. (I don't see how the other answer helps any more than this one did.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a generic type, in this case we call it `Transmuted<T>`. This generic type will transform the properties of `T` into `any` type. See below for code on how to go about it:

```
class Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: Date;
}

type Transmuted<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: any;
}

type TransmutedFoo = Transmuted<Foo>
```

So we use a mapped type to iterate through each of the properties `K` of `T` using the TypeScript `keyof` operator, and then, type `any` is assigned as the type for each of the property. Hope this helps!